# Windows 10 battery report - Full charge capacity exceeds design capacity

Tags: windows-10, sony-vaio, battery-life

I've replaced the battery twice on a Sony Vaio SVS15 with an aftermarket brand and have run into an odd result in Windows 10 battery report.

```
DESIGN CAPACITY         48,840 mWh
FULL CHARGE CAPACITY    49,410 mWh
```

This shows up and slowly increases(full charge capacity) after following each of the battery manufacturer's recommendation to discharge the battery completely to allow software estimates' re calibration. On initial install, the capacities match.

**With the first aftermarket battery:**

After fully charging to 100%, then unplugging the charger, the battery will reflect 96% within about a minute. It then seems to discharge much faster than the estimates given by Windows. At the 10% mark, the system shuts down unexpectedly, completely drained.

**Second aftermarket battery:**

Intermittently, it shows 96% and not charging - I can unplug the charger and back in to bring it to 100%. Upon reaching 10% remaining (10 minutes remaining estimate), it'll run for another couple minutes, then lose power.

Are there other ways to re-calibrate a system to properly report battery life, or could these simply be two faulty batteries?

Comment: Sounds like these aftermarket batteries are not worth the savings.  My guess their actual capacity is much much less then a genuine baattery

Comment: Sony has been known to [screw with users over 3rd party batteries](https://kurtsthoughts.com/2012/09/16/info-sony-vaio-error-the-installed-battery-may-not-be-properly-connected-to-the-computer-or-it-may-not-be-compatible-with-the-computer/). It’s one of the only brands I know that does this, and I’m not surprised you’re having issues with them.